# Como remover e adicionar classe HTML dinamicamente com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css-hover

Consegui resolver através do JQuery, porém queria uma solução apenas em JavaScript puro.

Tenho uma `nav` com 4 links no `header`, a `li` em que o usurário se encontra possui uma classe `selected` por padrão, que muda a cor e cria um pequeno traço embaixo.

Meu objetivo é: ao acontecer um `hover` em qualquer uma das `li`'s, essa classe `selected` saia da `li` principal e vá para onde o mouse estiver.

```js
var navegacaoA = document.querySelector('nav a');
navegacaoA.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    let navegacaoLi = document.querySelector('nav li');
    if (navegacaoLi.classList.contains('selected')) {
        navegacaoLi.classList.remove('selected');
        this.classList.add('selected');
    }
})
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected"><span></span><a href="">Invisalign</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Benefícios</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Serve para mim?</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Qual é o objetivo dessa classe? Estilização? Então porque não faz diretamente pelo `:hover` do CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, não sei se essa é a melhor solução, mas pelo que eu entendi sobre a sua necessidade, funciona. Invés de usar classe, eu usei um atributo, que podemos facilmente estilizar e desabilitar através do javascript

```js
    var li = document.querySelectorAll('li')
    var liSelected = document.querySelector('[selected=true]')
    for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        li[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            liSelected.setAttribute('selected', false)
            this.setAttribute('selected', 'true')
        })
        li[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
            liSelected.setAttribute('selected', true)
            this.setAttribute('selected', 'false')
        })
    }
```

```css
a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

[selected=true] a{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #00b;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li selected="true"><a href="">Invisalign</a></li>
    <li selected="false"><a href="">Benefícios</a></li>
    <li selected="false"><a href="">Serve para mim?</a></li>
    <li selected="false"><a href="">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está complicando demais, não precisa de nenhum JS para colocar/tirar sublinhado no mouseover, só CSS:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Invisalign</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Benefícios</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Serve para mim?</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```